# Unable to return response back to view in laravel from package

Tags: php, laravel

I am integrating [msg91-laravel package](https://github.com/craftsys/msg91-laravel) in one of my laravel app for OTP authentication. I am able to send and receive OTP using the package but I am unable to figure out how I can send back the response from the msg91 server back to view.

`AuthController.php`

```
public function loginWithMobile(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $countryCode =  $request->input('countryCode');
        $mobileNumber =  $request->input('mobileNumber');
        $fullmobileNumber = $countryCode.$mobileNumber;
        // Checking User
        if (User::where('mobileNumber', $fullmobileNumber)->exists()) {
                Msg91::otp()
                ->to($fullmobileNumber)
                ->template('61432d6c30afb372115d3062')
                ->send();


         }else{
            $userId = \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
            User::Create([
                'userId'    => $userId,
                'mobileNumber'    => $fullmobileNumber
                ]);
            Msg91::otp()
            ->to($fullmobileNumber)
            ->template('61432d6c30afb372115d3062')
            ->send();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for that package says that *"[a]ll the services will return \Craftsys\Msg91\Support\Response instance for all successfully responses"* so rather than just call the opt() method statically, assign it to a response :

```
$response = Msg91::otp()...
```

and then either process the response in your controller and pass the relevant sections to the view, or pass the response to your view wholesale.

You should also beef up your controller so that it captures the Exception that is returned from the opt() method if there is a problem, otherwise the code will just fall over.